# Failed to bind handlers: DNS Error: Not Implemented; retrying in 2 s

Tags: yagna

When trying to start Yagna I receive this error, what can I do? I can probably get some DEBUG logs if needed?

```
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  yagna] Starting yagna service! Version: 0.6.4 (4fc72117 2021-04-15 build #135).
Log is written to /home/user/.local/share/yagna/yagna_rCURRENT.log
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  yagna] Data directory: /home/user/.local/share/yagna
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  ya_sb_router::unix] Router listening on: "/tmp/yagna.sock"
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  ya_persistence::executor] using database at: /home/user/.local/share/yagna/yagna.db
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  ya_persistence::executor] using database at: /home/user/.local/share/yagna/market.db
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  ya_persistence::executor] using database at: /home/user/.local/share/yagna/activity.db
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  ya_persistence::executor] using database at: /home/user/.local/share/yagna/payment.db
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  ya_identity::service::identity] using default identity: 0xf5ecffecf053508fe97255e046a04ce21c8ee525
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  yagna] Identity GSB service successfully activated
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  ya_metrics::pusher] Metrics pusher started
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  yagna] Metrics GSB service successfully activated
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  ya_service_bus::remote_router] trying to connect to: /tmp/yagna.sock
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  ya_service_bus::connection] started connection to gsb
[2021-05-06T08:45:08Z INFO  ya_metrics::pusher] Starting metrics pusher
[2021-05-06T08:45:10Z INFO  yagna] Version GSB service successfully activated
[2021-05-06T08:45:10Z INFO  ya_net::service] using default identity as network id: 0xf5ecffecf053508fe97255e046a04ce21c8ee525
[2021-05-06T08:45:10Z WARN  ya_net::handler] Failed to bind handlers: DNS Error: Not Implemented; retrying in 2 s
[2021-05-06T08:45:12Z WARN  ya_net::handler] Failed to bind handlers: DNS Error: Not Implemented; retrying in 4 s
[2021-05-06T08:45:16Z WARN  ya_net::handler] Failed to bind handlers: DNS Error: Not Implemented; retrying in 8 s
```

EDIT: nslookup

```
Server:        10.139.1.1
Address:    10.139.1.1#53

** server can't find _net._tcp.dev.golem.network: NOTIMP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user has trouble reaching Google's DNS with nslookup, so it appears to be something on his end. He is also using a proxy for his connection, so it must happen somewhere in there. Closing thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is the reason here, but it seems like DNS is not able to resolve `_net._tcp.dev.golem.network` SRV record yielding 'Not Implemented'. It is very odd, since Yagna is using Google's DNS servers as a default.

When you face this again pls try to check output of following command

```
 nslookup -q=SRV _net._tcp.dev.golem.network 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: I've updated the nslookup to use Google DNS server. Pls run it and show output